# How to pass values between CDK stacks deployed in different accounts within a CDK app?

Tags: aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk

Reading from the documentation, the suggestion for passing values between CDK Stacks within an app is to simply pass the value.

> If the two stacks are in the same AWS CDK app, just pass a reference between the two stacks. For example, save a reference to the resource's construct as an attribute of the defining stack (this.stack.uploadBucket = myBucket), then pass that attribute to the constructor of the stack that needs the resource.

But it seems this only works if the CDK stacks are within one account.

Upon checking the generated templates, it generates a stack Output and Input and uses that for the passing values. And stack input and outputs does not work beyond the account they are created on.

What's the recommended way to pass values from stacks deployed in different accounts?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can think about this as being a single CDK application. Such a single application is intended to be deployed in a single account. What you are trying to do is use this application construct to deploy two different stacks in two different environments and share data between them. However, you are bound to the same restrictions that CloudFormation itself has when it comes to sharing data from services that have been deployed in the stack. So you'll have to work around this issue.

So I don't think there is any recommended way of doing this, but maybe you can create some cross-account roles that allow writing/reading from the SSM parameter store and combine this with custom resource lambdas to read/write the data from/in the SSM store of the other account. Given this, it might be easier to just write some CICD tooling that does this without needing any AWS services and which just passes on the value from the output of one stack to the input of the other stack during deployment.